# How to check if order, is users second order WooCommerce 3.x

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

So I want to redirect the user to a custom thankyou page, after checking if it's his second order or not. So if second order --> thankyou , else --> thankyou-2.

I have this code:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'mbm_redirect_depending_on_product_id');

function mbm_redirect_depending_on_product_id()
{

    if (!is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') || empty($_GET['key']))
    {
        return;
    }

    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($_GET['key']);
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item)
    {
        if {

            wp_redirect('/thankyou');
            exit;

        } else {
            wp_redirect('/thankyou-2');
            exit;
        }



        }
    }

}
```

What kind of if statement do I have to make to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function: `wc_get_customer_order_count()`

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_customer_order_count.html

```php
function mbm_redirect_depending_on_product_id() {
    if (!is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') || empty($_GET['key'])) {
        return;
    }

    $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($_GET['key']);
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Getting the user ID
    $user_id = $order->get_user_id();

    // Get the user order count
    $order_count = wc_get_customer_order_count( $user_id );

    if ( $order_count == 2 ) {
        wp_redirect('/thankyou');
        exit;
    } else {
        wp_redirect('/thankyou-2');
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mbm_redirect_depending_on_product_id');
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.